# Rotating two UiImageViews about one point

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

I'm working on my first iOS app, and would like to rotate two UIImageViews A and B about a point X in between them.

```
+-------+
|       |
|   A   |
|       |
|       |
+-------+
   [X]
+-------+
|       |
|   B   |
|       |
|       |
+-------+
```

So far, I've tried making a UIView (called twoShipView below) and placing the two ImageViews into it, and applying an animation to this UIView like this:

```
- (void)spinShipsWithOptions:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:options
                 animations:^{
                     self.twoShipView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.twoShipView.transform, M_PI / 2);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     if (finished) {
                         if (self.isAnimatingShips) {
                             [self spinShipsWithOptions:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear];
                         } else if (options != UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut) {
                             [self spinShipsWithOptions:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut];
                         }
                     }
                 }
    ];
}
```

**Expected result**: The View itself to rotate in an animated fashion, about it's centre. The ImageViews are ships, and I'd like to be able to insert other images and manipulate them inside this View's coordinate system, so I'd like to just have the View rotate and have the ImageViews just go along with what the View does.

**Actual result**: The View itself does not rotate. The two ImageViews do, and because the View is a portrait oriented rectangle, the rotation cuts off the other ImageView. The animation also does not take place.

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Thanks very much!
Ian

Comment: I tried you code, and the outer view that contains the two image views did rotate. If self.isAnimatingShips evaluated to YES, then I got a continuous rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I was calling the start animation in viewDidLoad, instead of viewDidAppear, by mistake. Thanks for your time everyone.